# Reliable source to learn about Protractor with Jasmine Framework in Eclipse with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse, selenium, protractor

I have to start work in my organisation over Angular JS application testing. Please specify some site to learn PROTRACTOR with JAVASCRIPT using JASMINE Framework . (Eclipse IDE will be helpful)

Thank you

Stackoverflow has been great help in enhancing my automation skills hope to get same for PROTRACTOR

Answer (score 0):

http://www.protractortest.org/

and

https://github.com/angular/protractor

and

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html

everything you need to learn protractorjs if you already familiar with how nodejs works, JavaScript, Async code execution, promises, Node Package Manager

Comment: Thank you Sir, but I have already gone through above link before posting Question . 
It will be great help if I get more other resource .